# How to change css of a Play link once the wav file is played completely in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed, media-player

I have a requirement to change the Play link css/image once the media file is played completely. Suppose that we have a Play icon when the page is loaded and when user clicks on the Play icon, it will change to Stop icon. Now the requirement is when ever the media file is played completely, stop icon must be changed Play icon automatically. Below is the sample HTML code we are using

CSS Code

```
<style>
.css-play{
height:21px;  display:block;cursor:pointer;
background: url(/images/backgrounds/ct_initial.gif) left top no-repeat;
}
.css-stop {
height:21px; display:block;cursor:pointer;
background: url(/images/backgrounds/ct_playing.gif) left top no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Javascript Code

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function Play(songname,ctrl)
    {
      document.getElementById("divEmbed").innerHTML='<embed id="sound" NAME="sound" src="'+songname+'"  autostart="true" type="audio/wav" ></embed>';
       ctrl.className  = 'css-stop';
    }
    </script>
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="divEmbed" > </div>
<a onclick="Play('preview.wav',this);" class="css-play" >click</a>
```

Looking for any sort of support

Comment: I would suggest you to go with any predefined mediaplayer , bcoz there are several conditions for which you need to write your own code again and again (for example, pause , loading, fastfarward etc..) and there is an advantage of additional plugins when you go with predefined media player. If you are going to create a project based on music, video just go by that and it will save lots of time.

Comment: @kvijayhari - My requirement is that there will not be any flash player on the page and there would be only Play link available, whenever user clicks on the link the audio plays in the background. Could you please suggest any good example or reference for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using a player, that is not possible. The `<embed>` tag exposes no events like HTML5's `<audio>` tag does. You would either have to use a sound-only flashmovie, that runs your action at the end by invoking it from actionscript. Or use a player, that exposes those events.

Comment: Hey Actually, My requirement is that there will not be any flash player on the page and there would be only Play link available, whenever user clicks on the link the audio plays in the background. Could you please suggest any good example or reference for this.

Comment: Without flash, you would have to hook into events a player offers. Look here: http://johnny-ray.com/swaggplayer/ for an example of a player that exposes events and relies on jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. That's really helped me. +1 and Accepted Answer